# Get users of SharePoint security group

Tags: jsom, central-administration, groups, ad, office-365-groups

How to get the users of SharePoint security group in JSOM.?

I followed several articles including this one:
[How to get user security group name through javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85146/how-to-get-user-security-group-name-through-javascript)

But none of them were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) and the [List members](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list_members) with [adaljs](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

Should be possible to delegate the permissions needed:

> Delegated (work or school account)
>   Directory.Read.All,
>   Directory.AccessAsUser.All, User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All

**Edit:**

I did a quick test, and its working okey:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'EN-ANSATTE'&$select=id", 
    method: "GET", 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept' : 'application/json; odata.metadata=none',
    },
    success: function(data) {                

        if(data.value.length) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/"+ data.value[0].id +"/members", 
                method: "GET", 
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'Accept' : 'application/json; odata.metadata=none',
                },
                success: function(dataMembers) {                

                    dataMembers.value.forEach((ele) => {
                        if(ele.percentComplete != 100) {
                            console.log( ele.userPrincipalName )
                        }
                    })

                }, 
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
        }      
    }, 
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

You'll have add an app with permissions etc to azure ad and get the token with adaljs. Lots of blogs how that's done on google

Comment: And h0ow to get the token value.? Not getting any article, clearly.

Comment: @DilipKumarYadav you can check this blogpost out: http://julieturner.net/series/extending-sharepoint-with-adal-and-the-microsoft-graph-api/ , should cover most iguess